# You can't see this rebus riddle

Tags: riddle, visual, rhyme, rebus, language

[image]

It is a rebus, fine 
But also a riddle 
It must be a sign 
Spoken but seen a little

Comment: Not sure if it means anything, but some basic image processing yielded [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nmu3.jpg).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it

> Blind Spot

not sure though,

> from curtisks answer and the last line : "Spoken but seen a little".
>  As, by definition : bind spot is, An area that is not able to be seen, either due to its location outside of the field of vision

Comment: Some explanation: I've removed the body from the sign. So only the "spot" and the "stick" left. And the riddle and the rest refers the English idiom.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it "Blind"? It reminded me of one of the standard street signs, not seen too often except in areas where blind people live

Comment: You are almost there. It is simple but not that simple. Well, I have to give another hint then: It is two words, not one word.

Comment: Just to be more clear, you found one of the words.

Answer (score 3):

> Morse code? Morse code uses dots and dashes. You can use it as a sign language to communicate (thats what some WWII POWs did in Japanese concentration camps) and its mostly spoken (or heard) in blips and bloops (more or less) and sometimes seen a little.

Comment: Nice try, not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Blind Corner Ahead?

Because:

> The sign looks like a warning to look out for blind pedestrians, but the stick figure is just a head, or "just ahead". The walking stick is pointing to a corner of the sign.

Comment: This seems like it, but @ermanen said in a comment that it's only two words. Remove "ahead" and it'd seem spot on!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it **sign language?** Just a guess; doesn't really fit the picture but it fits the third line: It must be a sign/Spoken but seen a little

Comment: Nope, "curtisk" found one of the words.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> Blind Turn

because it looks like a

> titled bicycle

Answer (score 2):

I think it’s

> “spot on”

because

> The dot is a “spot” and the line is either the “on” part of an on/off switch, or the spot is “on” the line (collinear).

Comment: How does this tie in to "You can't see this rebus riddle"?

Answer (score 1):

Building off @curtisk 's answer:

is it

> Blind drive?

As

> It follows street sign format, and "blind drive" is a common street sign (at least around me); the dot could represent Braille (used by the blind), and the line could indicate forward movement (=drive?).

Comment: Nope. So close. It is related to driving also.

Answer (score -1):

> Colour Blind

Because:

> it is black and white :) so you see less

Comment: Note the spoiler command `>!`